# setting up multiple queues using TORQUE

Tags: queue

I would like to set up two different queues using TORQUE on ROCKS.  Each would be functional for different sets of compute nodes, but all of these compute nodes can be accessed from the same mother node or head node. What I need to know is how to do this using the qmgr command. Also, I would like to know how to add different nodes in the two different queues.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Perhaps you could find solution here: [Queue Configuration](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/4.1queueconfig.shtml)